# when i select the date datepicker shows date in the incorrect dateformat?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following code the the datepicker

```
  $('#txtDOB').datepicker({
            appendText: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            dateFormat:'dd-mm-yyyy',
            showOn:'focus', 
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true                  
        });
```

MVC binds the date value to the text control as :

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.employee.DOB, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
 new {@class="form-control", id="txtDOB", 
 placeholder="Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY)", style="width:400px"})</td>
```

but when i select teh date from the datepicker the date value will be set to month?

eg.: when i select the date 22nd of January 2016 it sets the date as 11/22/2016 where 11 is todays day

the second issue is, `changeMonth:true` does not show the drop down

Comment: Is the culture on the server one that has the date format `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no its US time, but i have set the annotation to dd/MM/YYYY. when the page loads it shows in the correct date format but when select a date from the datepicker instead of updating date part of dd/mm/yyyy it updates the month part with the date value eg.: todays date 11/01/2016 when i select 22 of January it shows the selected date as 11/22/2016

Comment: You need to change the server culture, or use a custom `ModelBinder` to parse the date correctly when the value is posted back to the controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke oic, let me change back to US time and see!

Comment: @StephenMuecke when i changed it back to US time it worked, so you should be correct!

Comment: @StephenMuecke the second question ive posted the changeMonth:true does not work... any thoughts on why it does not show?

Comment: Not sure. I don't use the jquery-ui datepicker but according to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeMonth) it should work fine